# Add multiple cards on the same row

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I have this movie app in Spring Boot and I want to display 5 movie cards on the same row. This is what I have now:

```
<div class="my-4 card-columns">
    <div class="card" th:each="movie : ${listMovies}">
        <a th:href="@{/movie/{id}(id=${movie.id})}">
            <img class="card-img-top"
                 th:src="${movie.photosImagePath}"/>
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title" th:text="${movie.movieTitle}"></h5>
            <p class="card-text" th:text="${movie.movieGenre}"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how it looks in localhost:8080

[image]

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: yes i am using.

Comment: I suppose you use the newest version of Bootstrap which uses Flex for it's columns. However your images should fill that card otherwise things could be weird :)

Answer (score -1):

The following CSS code should work perfectly:

```css
.card-container{
            display: flex;
            gap: 10px; /*This feature may not work for all browsers*/
            width: 100vw; /*this is 100% percent of the screen viewable width*/
        }
        .card{
            flex-grow: 1;
        }
```

Just make sure to name the classes accordingly to match the ones in the css!

Comment: I downvoted this because Bootstrap already uses Flex in it's standard classes.

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/